# Extracting Functions/Code From an RDS file

Tags: r, list, rds

I reached out to a package developer for some assistance, and they recommended I download the tarball file from the website to obtain the necessary, original code files. I was able to download the file and found the following code to successfully read in one of the RDS files:

```
jason <- readRDS("C:/Desktop/junk/r/rdrobust_dwnld/rdrobust_0.99.6/rdrobust/Meta/Rd.rds", refhook = NULL)
```

Examining jason provides a listing of the files within the Rd.rds file:

[image: screen_shot]

I've been searching, but have been unsuccessful in finding a solution as to whether i can extract the code underlying the various files listed (e.g., rdplot)? There is a parameter in that file the developer has suggested i edit for my particular purposes, but it's not made available to general users.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Jason

Comment: You need to give the directions from the package developer, not just what you did after you got that file.

Comment: Verbatim: "You can always obtain the original code files by downloading the tar.gz file.  In there you will find all the functions and main codes. You will be able to manually choose the polynomial order k that we don't include as an option."